# Flask Sqlalchemy circular import when using blueprints

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a flask application which it's packages are separated each other using Blueprints.
I have 3 packages which have many to one relations.

The first package (blueprint) is Authentication (Containts User_Model):

```
from Billboard.Apps.models import Android_Model
from Billboard.Survey.models import Survey_Model

class User_Model (db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = user_model
    ...
    advertised_apps = db.relationship ('Android_Model' , backref = 'user_model' , lazy = True)
    advertised_surveys = db.relationship ('Survey_Model' , backref = 'user_model' , lazy = True)
```

the second package has foreign key to my User_Model:

```
from Billboard.Authentication.models import User_Model

class Survey_Model (db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'survey_model'
    ...
    advertiser_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_model.id'), nullable=False)
```

And the third package's model is same as second one.

When i run my flask app i got some imports error which i know they are for circular import between these models.

NOTE: when i remove this relation between these models, i got no error and project works correctly.

Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to import the model to declare a relationship with it. Notice `db.relationship` takes a string as a first argument and not a class.

Comment: so what should i write into db.relationship in this example ?

Comment: You just need to delete the imports, they're not necessary.

Comment: this is the error which it returns:
 When initializing mapper Mapper|User_Model|user_model, expression 'Android_Model' failed to locate a name ("name
 'Android_Model' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'Billboard.Authentication.models.User_
Model'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.